# error response status code was unacceptable: 405

Tags: ios, firebase, stripe-payments, alamofire

When I try to create PayMentIntent It shows follwing error (see image):-

[image]

My StripeViewController is: -

```
import UIKit
import Stripe
import Alamofire
import Firebase

 class StripeViewController: UIViewController, STPAuthenticationContext {

 // MARK: UIViews
 var productStackView=UIStackView()
 var paymentStackView=UIStackView()
 var productImageView=UIImageView()
 var productLabel=UILabel()
 var payButton=UIButton()
 var loadingSpinner=UIActivityIndicatorView()
 var outputTextView=UITextView()
 var paymentTextField=STPPaymentCardTextField()

 let backendURL : String =  "https://testpro-92351-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/"
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // Setup UI (images, labels, debug text view)
    // Also setup STPPaymentCardTextField from Stripe-iOS
    self.setupUI()
  }

 // MARK: UIView setup

 func setupUI() {
 setupProductImage()
 setupProductLabel()
 setupLoadingSpinner()
 setupPaymentTextField()
 setupPayButton()
 setUptOutputTextView()
    
 self.productStackView.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:70,width:330, height:150)
 self.productStackView.center.x = self.view.center.x
 self.productStackView.alignment = .center
 self.productStackView.axis = .vertical
 self.productStackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
 self.productStackView.addArrangedSubview(self.productImageView)
 self.productStackView.setCustomSpacing(10,after:self.productImageView)
 self.productStackView.addArrangedSubview(self.productLabel)

 self.view.addSubview(self.productStackView)

 self.paymentStackView.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:250,width:300,height:100)
 self.paymentStackView.center.x = self.view.center.x
 self.paymentStackView.alignment = .fill
 self.paymentStackView.axis = .vertical
 self.paymentStackView.distribution = .equalSpacing


 self.paymentStackView.addArrangedSubview(self.paymentTextField)
 self.paymentStackView.addArrangedSubview(self.payButton)

 self.view.addSubview(self.paymentStackView)
 }
    
 func setupProductImage() {
 self.productImageView = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x:50, y:50, width:275, height:200))

 self.productImageView.image = UIImage(named:"ic_cart")
 self.productImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

 }

func setupProductLabel() {
    self.productLabel.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:270, width: self.view.frame.width, height:50)
self.productLabel.text = "buy a stripe press book for $ 5"
self.productLabel.textAlignment = . center
 }

 func setUptOutputTextView() {
 self.outputTextView.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:420,width:self.view.frame.width-50, height:100)
 self.outputTextView.center.x = self.view.center.x
 self.outputTextView.textAlignment = .left
 self.outputTextView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:20)
 self.outputTextView.text = ""
 self.outputTextView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.purple.cgColor
 self.outputTextView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
 self.outputTextView.isEditable = false
 self.view.addSubview(self.outputTextView)
 }
 func setupPaymentTextField() {
 self.paymentTextField.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 300, height:50)
 }
    func setupPayButton() {
 self.payButton.frame = CGRect(x:60, y:480, width: 150, height:50)
 self.payButton.setTitle("submit payment", for:.normal)
        self.payButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for:.normal)
 self.payButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        self.payButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red:50/250,green:50/250,blue:90/250,alpha:1.0)
 self.payButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        self.payButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pay), for: .touchUpInside)
      }
 func setupLoadingSpinner() {
 self.loadingSpinner.color = UIColor.darkGray
 self.loadingSpinner.frame = CGRect(x:60, y:400, width: 25, height:25)
 self.loadingSpinner.center.x = self.view.center.x
 self.view.addSubview(self.loadingSpinner)
 }

 func startLoading() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.loadingSpinner.startAnimating()
        self.loadingSpinner.isHidden=false
     }
 }

  func stopLoading() {
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.loadingSpinner.stopAnimating()
        self.loadingSpinner.isHidden=true
     }
 }

 func displayStatus(_ message: String) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.outputTextView.text! += message + "\n"
         self.outputTextView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(self.outputTextView.text.count - 1, 1))
     }
  }

 // MARK: Button Actions

@objc func pay() {
    // 1) [server-side] Create a PaymentIntent
    // 2) [client-side] Confirm the PaymentIntent

    // make a POST request to the /create_payment_intent endpoint
    self.startLoading()
    self.displayStatus("Creating PaymentIntent")

    self.createPaymentIntent { (paymentIntentResponse, error) in
        if let error=error {
            self.stopLoading()
            self.displayStatus(error.localizedDescription)
            print(error)
            return
        }
        else {
            guard let responseDictionary=paymentIntentResponse as? [String: AnyObject] else {
                print("Incorrect response")
                return
            }

            print(responseDictionary)
            let clientSecret=responseDictionary["secret"] as! String

            self.displayStatus("Created PaymentIntent")

            // Confirm the PaymentIntent using STPPaymentHandler
            // implement delegates for STPAuthenticationContext

            let paymentIntentParams=STPPaymentIntentParams(clientSecret: clientSecret)
            let paymentMethodParams=STPPaymentMethodParams(card: self.paymentTextField.cardParams, billingDetails: nil, metadata: nil)
            paymentIntentParams.paymentMethodParams=paymentMethodParams

            STPPaymentHandler.shared().confirmPayment(withParams: paymentIntentParams, authenticationContext: self) { (status, paymentIntent, error) in

                self.stopLoading()

                var resultString=""

                switch (status) {
                case .canceled:
                    resultString="Payment canceled"
                case .failed:
                    resultString="Payment failed, please try a different card"
                case .succeeded:
                    resultString="Payment successful"
                }

                print(resultString)
                self.displayStatus(resultString)
            }
        }
    }

}

func createPaymentIntent(completion: @escaping STPJSONResponseCompletionBlock) {
    var url=URL(string: backendURL)!
    url.appendPathComponent("create_payment_intent")

   Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: [:])
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .responseJSON { (response) in
            switch (response.result) {
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(nil, error)
            case .success(let json):
                completion(json as? [String : Any], nil)
            }
    }

}

// MARK: STPAuthenticationContext Delegate

func authenticationPresentingViewController() -> UIViewController {
    return self
    }
 }
```

---

my index.js file

```
 import stripe
 import firebase

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const express = require('express')
admin.initializeApp();
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const stripe = require('stripe') ("sk_test_51HmAsMFzRM1fSBZ2CkBBjW5a3sEpxEQLGT7OkGxa8BZMMfgzT1Jeqs7dq63AlPRLIJmzHFC0HHAmKHDazcpriuh9001IWIVmw1");


 exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) =>       [![enter image description here][1]][1]{
 const customer = await stripe.customers.create({email: user.email});
 return admin.firestore().collection(‘stripe_customers’)
    .doc(user.uid).set({customer_id: customer.id});
 });



exports.addPaymentSource = functions.firestore
.document(‘/stripe_customers/{userId}/tokens/{pushId}’)
.onWrite(async (change, context) => {    const source = change.after.data();
const token = source.token;
if (source === null) {
    return null;
   }
 try {
 const snapshot = await
 admin.firestore()
 .collection(‘stripe_customers’)
 .doc(context.params.userId)
 .get();
 const customer = snapshot.data().customer_id;
 const response = await stripe.customers
    .createSource(customer, {source: token});
 return admin.firestore()
 .collection(‘stripe_customers’)
 .doc(context.params.userId)
 .collection(“sources”)
 .doc(response.fingerprint)
 .set(response, {merge: true});
 } catch (error) {
 await change.after.ref
    .set({‘error’:userFacingMessage(error)},{merge:true});
  }
 });
exports.createStripeCharge = functions.firestore
.document(‘stripe_customers/{userId}/charges/{id}’)
.onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
const val = snap.data();
try {
// Look up the Stripe customer id written in createStripeCustomer
const snapshot = await admin.firestore()
.collection(`stripe_customers`)
.doc(context.params.userId).get();

const snapval = snapshot.data();
const customer = snapval.customer_id;
// Create a charge using the pushId as the idempotency key
// protecting against double charges
const amount = val.amount;
const idempotencyKey = context.params.id;
const charge = {amount, currency, customer};
if (val.source !== null) {
   charge.source = val.source;
}
const response = await stripe.charges
    .create(charge, {idempotency_key: idempotencyKey});
// If the result is successful, write it back to the database
return snap.ref.set(response, { merge: true });
} catch(error) {
    await snap.ref.set({error: userFacingMessage(error)}, { merge: true });
  }
});
```

I have also put the "pktest____" in the AppDelegate.

As per definition, the HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 405 Method Not Allowed response status code indicates that the request method is known by the server but is not supported by the target resource.

Most Probably the cloud function is not connecting to json. How to sort it out ?

Edit: - MyAPIClient is:-

```
 import Stripe
 import UIKit

  class MyAPIClient: NSObject, STPCustomerEphemeralKeyProvider {
  let baseURL = URL(string: "https://api.stripe.com")!

    func createCustomerKey(withAPIVersion apiVersion: String, completion: @escaping STPJSONResponseCompletionBlock) {
        let url = self.baseURL.appendingPathComponent("ephemeral_keys")
        var urlComponents = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)!
        urlComponents.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "api_version", value: apiVersion)]
        var request = URLRequest(url: urlComponents.url!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request,  completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                response.statusCode == 200,
                let data = data,
                let json = ((try?   JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any]) as [String : Any]??) else {
                completion(nil, error)
                return
            }
            completion(json, nil)
        })
        task.resume()
      }
    }
```

Edit: -  @PaulAsjes -I have changed index.js as follows, after adding a webhook in my stripe, but still same error -

```
     const functions = require('firebase-  functions');
     exports.events =     functions.https.onRequest((request,    response) => {
     response.send("Endpoint for Stripe Webhooks!");
     });
     const functions = require(‘firebase-functions’);
     const stripe = require(‘stripe’)     (functions.config().keys.webhooks);
     const endpointSecret =        functions.config().keys.signing;exports.events =           functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
     response.send(“Endpoint for Stripe Webhooks!”);
    });

   // Get the signature from the request header
   let sig = request.headers["stripe-signature"];// Verify the      request against our endpointSecret
     let event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.rawBody, sig,   endpointSecret);
    let sig = request.headers["stripe-signature"];try {
    let event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.rawBody, sig,    endpointSecret);
    } catch (err) {
    return response.status(400).end();
    }
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp();...return     admin.database().ref('/events').push(event)
   .then((snapshot) => {
   return response.json({ received: true, ref:    snapshot.ref.toString() });
    })
   .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
   return response.status(500).end();
   });
```

Edit 2:

I have also tried with the following node.js code after reading stripe documents, but still no avail:-

```
   // This example uses Express to receive webhooks
   const app = require('express')();

  // Use body-parser to retrieve the raw body as a buffer
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

 // Match the raw body to content type application/json
 app.post('/webhook', bodyParser.raw({type: 'application/json'}),   (request, response) => {
  const event = request.body;

  // Handle the event
  switch (event.type) {
   case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
    const paymentIntent = event.data.object;
    // Then define and call a method to handle the successful  payment intent.
  // handlePaymentIntentSucceeded(paymentIntent);
  break;
  case 'payment_method.attached':
  const paymentMethod = event.data.object;
  // Then define and call a method to handle the successful   attachment of a PaymentMethod.
    // handlePaymentMethodAttached(paymentMethod);
    break;
   // ... handle other event types
   default:
  console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`);
  }

 // Return a response to acknowledge receipt of the event
 response.json({received: true});
 });

   app.listen(8000, () => console.log('Running on port 8000'));
 
      const stripe = require('stripe')      ('sk_test_51HmAsMFzRM1fSBZ2CkBBjW5a3sEpxEQLGT7OkGxa8BZMMfgzT1Jeqs7dq  63AlPRLIJmzHFC0HHAmKHDazcpriuh9001IWIVmw1'
);

     const endpointSecret = 'whsec_F71Gv4bMHueOwhQoks7KlEVjmXTHUMaO';


   const app = require('express')();


  const bodyParser = require('body-parser');


 app.post('/webhook', bodyParser.raw({type: 'application/json'}),   (request, response) => {
  const sig = request.headers['stripe-signature'];

    let event;

      try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.body, sig,   endpointSecret);
     }
     catch (err) {
   response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
  }

// Handle the event
  switch (event.type) {
  case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
  const paymentIntent = event.data.object;
  console.log('PaymentIntent was successful!');
  break;
    case 'payment_method.attached':
   const paymentMethod = event.data.object;
   console.log('PaymentMethod was attached to a Customer!');
    break;
   // ... handle other event types
     default:
  console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`);
   }

 // Return a response to acknowledge receipt of the event
  response.json({received: true});
   });

    app.listen(4242, () => console.log('Running on port 4242'));
```

Edit 3: I have changed index.js code now, still same error -

```
       const admin = require('firebase-admin');
       const express = require('express')
       admin.initializeApp();

      const functions = require('firebase-functions');
      const stripe = require('stripe')("sk_test_51HmAsMFzRM1fSBZ2CkBBjW5a3sEpxEQLGT7OkGxa8BZMMfgzT1Jeqs7dq63AlPRLIJmzHFC0HHAmKHDazcpriuh9001IWIVmw1");

    // When a user is created, register them with Stripe
     exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
 const customer = await stripe.customers.create({email:   user.email});
        return     admin.firestore().collection('uses').doc(user.uid).set({customer_id:    customer.id});
     });

       exports.createPaymentIntent = functions.https.onCall(async (req, res) => {

      const amount = req.amount;
     const customer = req.customer;
    console.log(customer)

     const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
     amount: 1099,
     currency: 'usd',
     });
     const clientSecret = paymentIntent.clientSecret
     console.log(clientSecret)
     return clientSecret
      });

      exports.getPaymentMethods = functions.https.onCall(async            (req, res) => {
     const customer = req.customer;
     const type = "card"

     stripe.paymentMethods.list({customer : customer, type:  type}, function(err, paymentMethods) {
     if (err !== null) {
     console.log("ERROR")
     } else {
    return paymentMethods
     }
    return
   })
   });

   exports.createEphemeralKey =  functions.https.onCall(async(data, context) => {
   const stripeVersion = data.stripe_version;
   const customerId = data.customer_id;

   return stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
   {customer: customerId},
   {stripe_version: stripeVersion}
   ).then((key) => {
    return key
   }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
   })
  })
```

Edit 3: new index.js after samthecodingman's comment -

```
 const functions = require('firebase-functions');
 const stripe_key =  "sk_test_51HmAsMFzRM1fSBZ2CkBBjW5a3sEpxEQLGT7OkGxa8BZMMfgzT1Jeqs7dq63AlPRLIJmzHFC0HHAmKHDazcpriuh9001IWIVmw1"
 const admin = require('firebase-admin');
 var stripe = require('stripe')(stripe_key);
 admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

 exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
 const full_name = data.full_name;
 const email = data.email;
 const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
  email: email,
  name: full_name,
  description: full_name
  });
 console.log('new customer created: ', customer.id)
 return {
  customer_id: customer.id
 }
 });

 exports.getStripeEphemeralKeys = functions.https.onCall(async      (data, context) => {
 const api_version = data.api_version;
 const customer_id = data.customer_id;
 const key = await stripe.ephemeralKeys.create (
  {customer: customer_id},
  {apiVersion: api_version}
 );
 return key;
 });

func createCustomerKey(withAPIVersion apiVersion: String,     completion: @escaping STPJSONResponseCompletionBlock) {
  let stripe_customer_id = MyDefaults.getDefaultsForCustID()
      functions.httpsCallable("getStripeEphemeralKeys").call(["api_version" : apiVersion, "customer_id" : stripe_customer_id]) { (response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            completion(nil, error)
        }
        if let response = (response?.data as? [String: Any]) {
            completion(response, nil)
           }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Your code is attempting to call a `/create_payment_intent` endpoint, but your firebase code doesn't appear to have that endpoint set up.

Comment: @PaulAsjes - I am not using stripe connect. Do I have to use stripe connect for that ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Connect. Your frontend code is trying to reach `/create_payment_intent`, but that endpoint doesn't appear to exist in the backend code you pasted here.

Comment: @PaulAsjes - I have changed index.js after adding a webhook(see comment), but still no avail

Comment: This also has nothing to do with webhooks. Your frontend code is calling a`createPaymentIntent` function which is trying to reach the endpoint `/create_payment_intent` on your server. That endpoint doesn't exist on your server. Search for `'/create_payment_intent'` in your firebase index.js code and you'll see it doesn't exist. Until you add that route there your code won't work.

Comment: @PaulAsjes - I have changed index.js code, still no avail.

Comment: If you are using `onCall` instead of `onRequest`, why are you trying to use Alamofire instead of using the Firebase SDK's callable functions methods? `functions.httpsCallable("createPaymentIntent").call([:])` ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#swift_1))

Comment: In addition, `backendURL`, which you have set as `https://testpro-92351-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/` is your Realtime Database's URL, not that of your cloud functions, which are instead hosted at `https://us-central1-testpro-92351.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_NAME` (with your current configuration)

Comment: @samthecodingman -  I chnged the url to "   "https://us-central1-testpro-92351.cloudfunctions.net/functions-1", it shows  404 error. How can I get the function name. Also, changed my index.js(see edit pease).

Comment: @samthecodingman - having issues with functions

Comment: @askit Please be patient and don't ping me more than once. I'm not paid to sit on StackOverflow all day and only jump on when I'm on break or have some free time. I'll come back to this when I get the chance.

Comment: Sorry to offend you, but this problem is pestering me for quite some-time. I will be highly obliged if this is sorted. I will not disturb you now.

Comment: @PaulAsjes - The whole issue is that I want my firestore uid to get added as my stripe customer id. when I press a button on the viewcontroller. What am I missing out on ?

Answer (score 3):

#### Client Request Problem

The reason why you are encountering a [`405 Method Not Allowed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405) error is because you are trying to `POST` a request to `https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/create_payment_intent`, which is a URL for a location on your project's Firebase Realtime Database. By trying to access the database this way, you are accidentally making use of the [Firebase RTDB REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database) which is what is returning the `405` error code.

To invoke a [HTTP Event Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events), you should be targeting `https://[FUNCTION_REGION]-[PROJECT_ID].cloudfunctions.net/[FUNCTION_NAME]`.

The following export:

```js
exports.createPaymentIntent = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => { /* ... */ });
```

would be accessed using:

```swift
let url : String = "https://us-central1-testpro-92351.cloudfunctions.net/createPaymentIntent"
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: ["amount": 1099])
    .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
    .responseJSON { (response) in
        switch (response.result) {
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(nil, error)
            case .success(let json):
                completion(json as? [String : Any], nil)
        }
    }
```

Instead of using Alamofire, you could use Firebase's own [Callable Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), as an added bonus, passing the currently signed in user's ID token is handled automatically for you.

The following export:

```js
exports.createPaymentIntent = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => { /* ... */ });
```

would be accessed using:

```swift
functions.httpsCallable("createPaymentIntent").call(["amount": 1099]) { result, error in
  if let error = error as NSError? {
    if error.domain == FunctionsErrorDomain {
      let code = FunctionsErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)
      let message = error.localizedDescription
      let details = error.userInfo[FunctionsErrorDetailsKey]
    }
    // ...
  }
  if let data = result?.data as? [String: Any] {
    // do something with data
  }
}
```

#### Cloud Functions Code

The following code blocks are all contained in `[PROJECT_DIR]/functions/index.js`. Here we'll be making use of [Callable Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) for the API.

The top of your file should be just:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_...');

// initialize admin SDK with defaults
admin.initializeApp();
```

To help link a Firebase User to their Stripe Customer ID, we can tweak the `auth.onCreate()` Cloud Function so that **new users** have their Firebase UID added to their Stripe Customer record's metadata and their Stripe Customer ID added to their Firebase ID Token:

```js
exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.auth.user()
  .onCreate(async (user) => {
    /** Options to pass to `stripe.customers.create()` */
    const createCustomerParams = {
      metadata: {
        firebase_uid: user.uid // store Firebase User ID in customer's metadata
      }
    };
    
    // If the user's primary email has been set for their
    // Firebase user, also pass it to Stripe
    if (user.email) {
      createCustomerParams.email = user.email;
    }
    
    const customerResponse = await stripe.customers.create(createCustomerParams);
    
    const stripeCustomerId = customerResponse.id;
    
    const stripeCustomerDocRef = admin.firestore()
      .collection('stripe_customers')
      .doc(user.uid);
    
    // Save Stripe Customer ID to Firestore and the user's ID token
    const [storeInFirestoreResult, setCustomClaimResult] = await Promise.all([
      stripeCustomerDocRef
        .set({ customer_id: customerResponse.id })
        .then(() => true, (err) => ({ error })),
      admin.auth()
        .setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, { stripe: stripeCustomerId })
        .then(() => true, (err) => ({ error }))
    ]);
    
    let hasError = false;
    
    if (storeInFirestoreResult !== true) {
      console.error(`Failed to store this user's (#${user.uid}) stripe customer ID (#${stripeCustomerId}) in Firestore: `, storeInFirestoreResult.error);
      hasError = true;
    }
    
    if (setCustomClaimResult !== true) {
      console.error(`Failed to store this user's (#${user.uid}) stripe customer ID (#${stripeCustomerId}) in their token claims: `, setCustomClaimResult.error);
      hasError = true;
    }
    
    if (hasError) {
      return Promise.reject("One or more subtasks failed");
    }
  });
```

Because we can now pull the Stripe Customer ID from the user token or Firestore, we can pull this logic into a reusable function:

```js
/** Takes a `CallableContext#auth` variable and returns its linked Stripe Customer ID */
async function getStripeCustomerId(auth) {
  // if the user's token has their stripe ID, return it
  if (auth.token.stripe) {
    return auth.token.stripe;
  }

  const stripeCustomerDocRef = admin.firestore()
      .collection('stripe_customers')
      .doc(auth.uid);
      
  return stripeCustomerDocRef.get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      if (!snapshot.exists) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
          'failed-precondition',
          'This user hasn\'t been linked with Stripe'
        );
      }
    
      return snapshot.get("customer_id");
    });
}
```

In your code you make use of an unspecified `userFacingMessage` method, to help us use it with [`HttpsError`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.httpserror) (the shown-to-user error type used for callable functions, see the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors)) we define these functions:

```js
/**
 * Takes a generic error object and returns a error message
 * for viewing by the user.
 */
function userFacingMessage(error) {
  // TODO: Replace with what you are using
  return error.code || error.message;
}

/**
 * Takes a generic error object and rethrows it as a
 * `functions.https.HttpsError` for consumption by the
 * function caller.
 */
function rethrowAsUnknownHttpsError(error) {
  // see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.httpserror
  throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
    'unknown',
    userFacingMessage(error)
    // you can pass an optional third argument for "details"
  );
}
```

Now that we have the basics set up, we can move on to the scaffold to create more functions that just return the response from the Stripe API:

```js
exports.FUNCTION_NAME = functions.https
  .onCall(async (data, context) => {
    if (!context.auth) {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        'failed-precondition',
        'The function must be called while authenticated.'
      );
    }

    const customer = await getStripeCustomerId(context.auth);

    const { /* get relevant data */ } = data;

    return stripe.CATEGORY.METHOD(params)
      .catch(rethrowAsUnknownHttpsError);
  });
```

If you need to mutate/change the response before sending it back, you can use:

```js
exports.FUNCTION_NAME = functions.https
  .onCall(async (data, context) => {
    if (!context.auth) {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        'failed-precondition',
        'The function must be called while authenticated.'
      );
    }

    const customer = await getStripeCustomerId(context.auth);

    const { /* get other relevant data */ } = data;

    const rawResponse = await stripe.CATEGORY.METHOD(params)
      .catch(rethrowAsUnknownHttpsError);

    const response = {};
    // do something with response & rawResponse
    return response;

    // you could even just use `return response.prop` if
    // you are only plucking a single property out
  });
```

As an example of the previous code blocks in action, let's write a function to connect the Firebase User and Stripe Customer like in the latest version of `createStripeCustomer` above:

```
exports.linkStripeCustomer = functions.https
  .onCall(async (data, context) => {
    if (!context.auth) {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        'failed-precondition',
        'The function must be called while authenticated.'
      );
    }

    if (context.auth.token.stripe) {
      // prevents calling this function multiple times unnecessarily
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        'already-exists',
        'This user has already been linked to their customer data'
      );
    }

    const stripeCustomerId = await getStripeCustomerId(context.auth);

    const customerResponse = await stripe.customers.update(
      stripeCustomerId,
      {
        metadata: {
          firebase_uid: context.auth.uid
        }
      }
    )
      .catch(rethrowAsUnknownHttpsError);

    await admin.auth()
        .setCustomUserClaims(context.auth.uid, { stripe: stripeCustomerId });
    
    return { success: true };
  });
```

Comment: functions.httpsCallable("createPaymentIntent").call - Cannot find 'functions' in scope. Having issues with functions.

Comment: @askit Read the [linked documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) and [the relevant code sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/b5dd1e0061c47009305d52ec2168b6de022d026d/functions/FunctionsExampleSwift/CommentCell.swift#L31-L48) in full.

Comment: Awarded bounty, otherwise would have expired, 'll figure out the solution later.